# Is there any way to use a for loop with 2 variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I was trying to web scrape data from a website but with no success.
I have run tests in the terminal and I seem to have no problem with running a for loop to print one list. The problem comes when I try to use 2 variables in a for loop.
I have tried to use `zip` but it doesn't seem to be working. Since I didn't know about how to use zip, I have checked other pages in StackOverflow but nothing seems to be working with my case.
This is the code I came up with:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
countries = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("mt_a")
cases = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("sorting_1")
[print(i.text, '-', j.text) for i, j in zip(countries, cases)]
```

When I tried running the program both from my IDE and terminal, nothing happened.
Can anyone please help me solve this issue?
All help appericiated.

Comment: There's a couple possible issues here. 1: Unless this is being run in a REPL, you need to explicitly `print` out the results of the last line. 2: If either `cases` or `countries` are empty, there won't be anything to iterate, and the last line won't do anything. Double check your data.

Comment: Please do not use the sideeffect of generating a list comprehension. They are there to build lists, not to replace simply for loops to print something. See [is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Comment: Debug your code: `print(list(cases))` and `print(list(countries))` if either is empty nothing will be done as zip() only works up to the shortest lists length

Answer (score 1):

You should first test with easier data, like `list1 = ['a', 'b']` and `list2 = [11, 22]`.

How about:

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = [11, 22]
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i, j)
```

Then, I'm not sure about what you are expecting with the print inside of the list?

```py
foo = [print(i, j) for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
print('foo =', foo)
```

returns the following:

```
a 11
b 22
foo = [None, None]
```

Comment: This does work as with this list but I'm really not sure where is the problem with my code

Comment: @nojif Are your lists empty? Try `print(len(countries), len(cases))`.

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, need to use `find_element_by_class_name` method instead of `find_elements_by_tag_name`.

Here are some parts of the HTML from https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ page

```
<td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; text-align:left;">
  <a class="mt_a" href="country/us/">USA</a>
</td>
...
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right" class="sorting_1">1,049,431</td>
```

Tags are: `td`, `a`

Classes are: `mt_a`, `sorting_1`